# Getting a Table Row from TableView in Titanium Mobile

Tags: javascript, user-interface, titanium

I'm trying to manipulate a tableViewRow inside a TableView but I can't find where it actually is stored. When inspecting Tableview, I get the headings under which the Rows should be, but I don't see any actual Rows.
Any idea in which Object these Rows are contained?

Comment: You can use table click event listener to get any specific row.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are not using table view section then, you can get all rows like this:

```
var rows = tableview.data[0].rows;
```

Comment: this works for tableview sections too... data[i] is the array containing the sections.